# Алгоритм создания из строки списка в python

Tags: python, строки, list

у меня есть на странице слова которые идут так:

```
001 003 
TH FH 
FS SC 
FSname SCname
```

мне нужно чтобы пользователь просто взял и передал это через фронт в обычный input или textarea и у него получился список типа:

```
L=["001 003", "TH FH", "FS SC", "FSname SCname"]
```

как это сделать, я даже понять не могу как сюда подступиться, так как обычный replace здесь не поможет

Дополнено: после слов перед переходом на след строку есть пробел, после последнего элемента пробела нет

Дополнено2: пользователь имеет скопированным выше описанный текст и вставляет его в форму на сайте, в данный момент форма на сайте представляет собой HTML тег textarea, эти данные отсылаются на сервер в виде:

```
te xt
te xt2
```

Comment: `input().split('\n')`

Comment: Если вы общаетесь с фронтом. В тексте присылаемом на бэк, должны быть разделители строк, по ним и нужно разделить сообщение. Приведите в вопросе более подробный формат данных присылаемый на бэкенд

Comment: В любом случае, следует попробовать split('\n') по переменной в которой содерж. данные с фронта

Comment: @Exord секундочку щас попробуем

Comment: @Exord Вышло, но с определенными нюансами, ['Kuos lian \r', 'Midas Tsyb \r', 'Kuos lian \r', 'Midas Tsyb \r', 'Kuos lian \r', 'Midas Tsyb'] список теперь выглядит так, осталось понять как сразу убрать эти "\r". При входных данных: Kuos lian 
Midas Tsyb 
Kuos lian 
Midas Tsyb 
Kuos lian 
Midas Tsyb

Comment: \r это возврат каретки. Попробуйте split('\r\n')

Comment: либо L = [x.replace('\r', '') for x in L]

Comment: @Exord Большое вам спасибо, вы прям спасли нас! Если хотите дайте ответ на дынный пост чтобы я смог засчитать его правильным

Comment: Если в элементах остануться лишние пробелы -  их можно убрать через функцию строки strip()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте `text.split('\r\n')` по тексту, пришедшему с фронта.

Получите нужный вам список. Мусорные пробелы по краям, можно удалить через strip() обращаясь к элементу строки.

```
text = [x.strip() for x in text.split('\r\n')]
```

Comment: У меня есть шанс дать только один input несколько не подходит

Comment: Ну, я думаю что так не получится. Предложенный input().split('\n') работать не будет. input <- никак не поддерживает ввод нескольких строчек в вашем формате. Может ли вам подойти чтение из файла? Если да, отредактируйте вопрос, и я изменю свой код.

Comment: в любом случае - я подправил код. теперь input() в коде один. Но вызываться он будет столько раз - сколько будет строк с вводом

Comment: К сожалению нет, я работаю с беком и у меня задачи из значения переменно переданной через фронт сделать список. Общаясь с фронтом мы понять не можем как тогда нам сделать чтобы это работало, так как юзер будет вносить данные только в выше описанным виде

Comment: Изменил код, в соответствии с дополнениями